# Multiple asPercent series

Tags: grafana, graphite

Metrics example - `something.{variable}.success` & `something.{variable}.total`

What I want to achieve is multiple series graph containing the `success` percentage for each feature `variable`.

Trying `asPercent(something.*.success, something.*.total)` makes graphite simply return 400 in grafana.

As I understand I would be able to achieve this by `applyByNode()`, but it seems that it's not available in grafana's graphite integration? I'm using self-hosted grafana 7.0 with graphite 1.1.7 .

I also seen example of nesting reduceSeries and mapSeries, but all of them use predefined values for wildcard, in my case there are too many of them to bother.